# Borel-set, open, measurable function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I have a questions about Borel sets. Here is how they defined in my book:

[image: pic]

**Now they say that, the set consits of open sets. But it must not nececarrily be all open sets on X?**

The reason this created a problem for me is the following proof.

[image: pic]

**How can they know that this exact open set is contained in the Borel-sigma algebra?**

Just so you have the info I will also give you my books definition of a measurable function:

[image: pic3]

Comment: You are misunderstanding the definition. The sigma-algebra is generated by the collection of *all* open sets. Also, in general, it contains sets that are not open: It contains all closed sets, for example, all countable unions of closed sets, all complements of these countable unions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Borel $\sigma$-algebra $B$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing *all open sets*. So, by definition *any* open set is containing in $B$. Of course, not every set in $B$ is open. For instance, since $(-1/n, 1+1/n) \in B$ for all natural numbers $n$, so is the intersection of these sets, which is the *closed* interval $[0,1]$.